# Assume f(z) is analytic in a domain R and never vanishes, but for some $z_{o}$ in R: $|f(z_{o})|=min(|f(z)|)$ in R. How to prove that f is constant?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

I tried solving this question by taking the derivative of f(z) = u(x,y) +iv(x,y). Then setting the derivative to zero at $z_o$. But doing this did not give any useful insight. I am generally confused by how I can relate f(z) never vanishing and being constant but there being a minimum value among the values of |f(z)|.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3413060/42969

Comment: Without loss of generality you may suppose that $f(z_0)\in\mathopen]0\mathbin;+\infty\mathclose[$.
Now, if $f$ isn't constant, there is a smaller $k\geqslant1$ such that $f^{(k)}(z_0)\neq0$, then $f(z_0+h)=f(z_0)+\alpha h^k+o(h^k)$ when $h\to0$ (for some $\alpha\neq0$).
For _some convenient choice_ for $h$, one obtains that $|f(z_0+h)|<f(z_0)$; a contradiction.